# numpy where function vs elements matching a condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's say I want to replace all elements of an array greater than 0 with 0. 
Which method should I go with?

```
array[array>0]=0
```

or

```
array[np.where(array>0)]=0
```

Comment: Use the first; this is what its there for. The second does not make sense. See the documentation for [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

Comment: Either one is fine.  "A single boolean index array is practically identical to x[obj.nonzero()] "  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing

Comment: @Brian, `np.where` as alias for `np.nonzero` is still widely used.  That warning note is relatively new.